# PHP How to redirect the user before doing the rest of the script

Tags: php

I got a php script (on top of my html file) that doing some SSH and MySQL that taking very long to finish.
looks like that:

```
if (!empty($_POST['install'])) {
 // the script action
 // some ssh & mysql stuff
}
```

now i'm trying to do that:

```
if (!empty($_POST['install'])) {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "logged.php?a=s_created";</script>';
 session_write_close(); // unlink the session so it wont slow the user
 // then do the rest of the code that slows up the session/page
}
```

but for some reason it wont echo the script tag..

the `&_POST['install']` refering to a form submit event, so everytime someone sumbiting the form its reloading the page with the post request of the form.

Comment: Nothing is returned to the browser until the whole script has ended. So your JavaScript won't be seen or executed until the rest is done

Comment: how I can fix it then? (not a php dev..)

Comment: Consider making the long-running functionality into a background job. Then the request from the browser might just using the PHP to set a flag in your database which then informs a separate script running via cron to carry out the SQL and ssh tasks. Then you can return from the main request immediately. That's just one example of how you could potentially tackle this, but a lot may depend on your environment, the specific requirements and the rest of your existing architecture

Comment: sadly i have to make on the same page and not as a background process, is there any way to separate the echo script and the process?