# PHP Script is taking too long. How I can make it into a separate task or run it in the background?

Tags: php

I got a form that starts a long script using mysql and ssh, sometimes its taking too much to finish, and its making the whole page loading until its finishing the task.
I already got one step by placing `session_write_close();` on the task start, so it wont slow the user session.
but still cant make it redirect the user to another page on the task start, before its starting the long proccess.
the code looks like that:

```
if (!empty($_POST['install'])) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "logged.php?a=s_created"; </script>'; // since 'header' doesnt work here
  session_write_close();
  // the long task....
}
```

i can make it on ajax instead, but I got too many variables on the same page, that i cant pass on the "data" of the ajax call.
how i can fix the issue without going to ajax?

Comment: _but I got too many variables on the same page_ To many for what? To many to bother coding the AJAX call or is there some limit you have reached

Comment: too many variables that i can't pass in the ajax call, I prefer not to pass php variables from the client side to another php script for security issues..

Comment: You basically asked the same thing the other day and I already proposed a solution, but you have not fully responded - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69517773/php-how-to-redirect-the-user-before-doing-the-rest-of-the-script. So why are you asking again? You said you "have" to do it on the same page and not as a background process, but didn't explain why. That sounds like an aribtrary restriction to me, but maybe you can clarify.

Comment: P.S. `I prefer not to pass php variables from the client side to another php script for security issues` ...it's unclear why using AJAX would affect this. If you trigger the script via a normal link or postback then you'd have to pass the same information, surely. The trigger method is irrelevant to the data which is required for the request to run. So if it's a security concern for AJAX, then it's also a security concern for any other route.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way to handle this, if it's really a slow, resource-intensive task, is to place an instruction to run the task in a queue, ideally in a dedicated table in a database, but you can also just place it in a file somewhere, and then have a cron daemon run a script at regular intervals, and that script checks the queue and if anything is it in, it runs the task.

So for example a crontab to run a script once a minute might look like:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/the_script.php
```

If it's less important to get it done fast, you can run it less often.

The script run by the cron daemon can be written in PHP (which can be convenient if you want to just reuse or move code) or it can be written in some other language (which can also be convenient if you want to do something that is easier to do in another language.)

In the script, you first check to see if a task is in the queue and not marked as in-progress or completed, then before starting, you update it to mark that it is in-progress.

Then, that script can do whatever error handling and processing of the results, and when the task completes or fails, delete the queue entry or mark it as completed or failed, and store any relevant results or error messages in a database, if necessary. You can use the returned info either to give feedback to users, or to be privately visible only to the admin to debug errors.

One advantage of this approach is that, if the script is particularly resource-intensive, you can limit how many such tasks are running. So for instance, say you only want one such task running at once. Then you can make it so that the script will just abort if any tasks are in progress. Since it runs every minute, it'll pick up the next item in the queue as soon as the previous one is completed. Or, if your server can handle a fixed amount of such tasks, you can allow a certain fixed number to run in the background.

To the user, you can either use AJAX or a fully syncronous, flat webpage, to put items in the queue and/or check if they've been updated. Instead of having the AJAX call actually initiate the script, you have it put something in a queue and perhaps return only an ID number, corresponding to the row in the database that was added to the queue. You can then query this row to see if it has been processed, and update it on the page, if you want realtime info to display to the user that the task has been completed. If you want a really simple way, you don't even need to use AJAX, you can just have the addition to the queue be handled by a single web request like a POST call, and then redirect the user to a page that perhaps refreshes every minute or two until the task is completed or aborts, if it's relevant for the user to wait. If the user doesn't need to wait, you can just redirect them somewhere else.